# How can we import `users` schema sequelize modal in server.js file in `ES6` way

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

How can we import `users` schema modal in server.js file in `ES6` way. Even though I have added `type: module` in package.json file it doesn't work, throws below error.

note: I am trying to import all of the other modules in ES6 way.

sequelize `user.js`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const users = sequelize.define('users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        tableName: 'users'
    });

    return users;
};
```

and in the `server.js`

```
import usersSchema from "./modals/users.js";
```

Throws below error in console:

node:40244)

```
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Project\study\matblogs\src\server.js:23
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```js
export default = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  ...
```

Refer to this ES6 101 article which will help you adjust your code: [ES6 In Depth: Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/)

> If you’d like your own ES6 module to have a default export, that’s easy to do.  There’s nothing magic about a default export; it’s just like any other export, except it’s named "default". You can use the renaming syntax we already talked about:
>
> ````
> ```js
> let myObject = {
>   field1: value1,
>   field2: value2
> };
> export {myObject as default};
> ```
> ````
>
> Or better yet, use this shorthand:
>
> ```js
> export default {
>   field1: value1,
>   field2: value2
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the server.js file is not being recognized as an ES module. To fix this issue, you need to add "type": "module" in your package.json file.

Comment: Thank you, I did tried that earlier ..at that time I was getting error ...
 
`import usersSchema from "./modals/users.js";
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './modals/users.js' does not provide an export named` 'default'